# Simultaneous operations on KStream & KTables

Tags: java, apache-kafka, stream, apache-kafka-streams

I'm trying to implement a use case in Kafka Streams where I populate a Ktable based on applying some filters on this stream, let's call this table a tracking table where the key is derived from the event and the value is the event.
Now for subsequent events I check this table to verify if they're tracked and update the event if it's tracked or publish it to a different topic. I'm not sure how to do this simultaneously. Here's what I have so far.

```
// Branch based on conditions
KStream<String, Event>[] segregatedRecords = branches[0]
                       .branch((key, event) -> event.getStatus().getStatus().equals("A"),
                        (key, event) -> event.getStatus().getStatus().equals("B"),
                        (key, event) -> event.getStatus().getStatus().equals("C"),


// Store events with status A to a topic
segregatedRecords[0]
                .selectKey((key, event) -> createKey(event))
                .mapValues(transform)
                .to(intermediateTopic);

// Load topic from previous step as GlobalKtable
GlobalKTable<String, Event> trackedEvents = streamsBuilder.globalTable(intermediateTopic);

// The following step is where I'm stuck, because I can not perform conditional actions
// If the event exists in the tracking table (update) but if not then how to publish it to a different topic?
segregatedRecords[1]
                 // derive key for lookup
                .selectKey((key, event) -> createKey(event))
                // update the event status in the table 
                .join(trackedEvents, (key, value) -> key,(event, tracked) -> modifiedEvent
                ).to(intermediateTopic);

// Other events will need to refer the latest information in the tracked table for further processing
```

Comment: Mabye a `leftJoin` could also help with a consecutive `branch()` that checks if the "right hand" value of the result is `null` or not.

Comment: I did try that out, but if I understand you correctly there's still the question of updating the right hand value as well, based on conditions down the topology. A left join would update the stream but the table state wouldn't be updated.

Comment: Oh yes. I missed that you also want to update the state. For this case a `leftJoin()` would not work. Sorry for the confusion. My bad.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do this by branching `segregatedRecords[1]` into 2 sub-Topology, one branch performs table lockup as your code, and the other branch uses low level processor API (using a transformValues in this case) to check whether the underlying `GlobalKTable` state store contains the record for the new derived key, if the record exists then transform the Event to `null` Event, then we filter out event which have null `Event` (because those events we already joined in the your first sub-Topology).
I updated your code a little bit:

```
//give your GlobalKTable a name to query later
GlobalKTable<String, Event> trackedEvents = streamsBuilder.globalTable(intermediateTopic, Materialized.as("tracked_event_global_store"));

KStream<String, Event> derivedKStream = segregatedRecords[1]
    // derive key for lookup
    .selectKey((key, event) -> createKey(event));
// this sub-topology perform table lockup as normal: update the event status in the table
derivedKStream.join(trackedEvents, (key, value) -> key,(event, tracked) -> modifiedEvent)
    .to(intermediateTopic);
// this sub-topology check whether the event existed in trackedEvents, if yes then event has been already joined 
// so we transform to null value and filter in next step 
derivedKStream.transformValues(() -> new ValueTransformerWithKey<String, Event, Event>() {
    //get the underlying store of Tracked GlobalKTable
    KeyValueStore<String, Event> trackedKvStore;
    @Override
    public void init(ProcessorContext context) {
        //using the previous name
        trackedKvStore = (KeyValueStore<String, Event>) context.getStateStore("tracked_event_global_store");
    }

    @Override
    public Event transform(String derivedKey, Event event) {
        //if event existed in trackedEvents then return a null event so we can filter out in next pipe
        if (trackedKvStore.get(derivedKey) != null) {
            return null;
        }
        //event not exist in trackedEvents, keep the event and send to different topic
        return event;
    }

    @Override
    public void close() {
    }
})
.filter((derivedKey, event) -> event != null)
.to("your different toic name");
```

**Update** : about the problem where you can not create both a GlobalKTable and a KStream from single topic `intermediate` (can not read a topic multiple time [as described here](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/KAFKA-6687)):

1. Create a dedicated input topic for `GlobalKTable` (this topic must have log compaction enabled):

```
KStream<Object, Object> intermediateKStream = streamsBuilder.stream(intermediate);
intermediateKStream.to(trackedInputTopic);
//instead of building GlobalKTable from intermediate, use this dedicated topic trackedInputTopic
GlobalKTable<String, Event> trackedEvents = streamsBuilder.globalTable(trackedInputTopic, Materialized.as("tracked_event_global_store"));

//Perform things you want to do with the intermediate topic
intermediateKStream
        ...
```

Comment: Thank you Tuyen, this is just what I was looking for. I'll test it and let you know.

Comment: It works for updates but turns out I cannot stream from the GlobalKtable. The last part was to query just the Global Ktable and filter out existing records and publish them to a third topic. But when I try to stream it throws me this error:-
```
Invalid topology: Topic "intermediate" has already been registered by another source.

Comment: The updated table holds all the information I need but I cannot query it without passing a stream, or branch it or stream it. There is an open ticket for this. Take a look. Any suggestions?
https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/KAFKA-6687

Comment: is your "branches[0]" KStream or above this KStream also stream() from the topic "intermediate"?

Comment: It seems that you can stream from a topic and create a KStream and KTable but currently there is no solution for GlobalKTable because GlobalKTable using the input topic for fault tolerance. I can only think of a workaround which is sending to a separated input topic for GlobalKTable but it's different problem though (by add a sub-Topology and send duplicated data to this topic).

Comment: To answer your first question, yes, there's a stream above branch[0].
Would you please be able to elaborate on the workaround?

Comment: @noobnoob yes, I updated to add a section on answer